# Referencing one Dimension of a Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: c

I have some C code that works great, but I do not understand one part of the code. In this part it passes a method two pointers to a two dimensional array with only one dimension specified.

Here it is:

```
if (cmppt(pts[i*3], pts[hull*3])) 
      hull = i;
```

the method cmppt looks like this:

```
inline bool cmppt(const float* a, const float* b) { 
      if (a[0] < b[0]) return true;
      if (a[0] > b[0]) return false; 
      if (a[2] < b[2]) return true; 
      if (a[2] > b[2]) return false; 
      return false; 
}
```

The array pts is a two-dimensional array. My question is, when the method is passed both arrays for example pts[3] and pts[0] how do I know what part of the array is it looking at? It seems that pts[0] looks at the first element of the first dimension of the array and pts[3] look at the second element of the first dimension of the array, but this doesn't make sense.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show where `pts` is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pts[i*3]` is equivalent to `&pts[i*3][0]`, which is a pointer to the first element of the `i*3`rd row of the 2D array.  Likewise, `pts[hull*3]` is a pointer to the first element of the `hull*3`rd row of the array.

So, the function `cmppt` takes pointers to two rows of an array.  It doesn't know *which* rows it's looking at, it only knows that it is looking at rows.

Answer (score 1):

its because when you say pts[i*3] what you are really saying is pts[i*3][].  2 dimentional arrays have rows and columns... you passed it the row.

your array (jagged) looks like this:

```
    int[][] pts = 
    {
        new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    };
```

then you pass it in to the function like this basically:

```
cmppt(int[] a, int[] b)
```